# Compute the Cayley table of $\mathbb{Z}^*_{10}$

Tags: group-theory

Could someone please help me with this question: Compute the Cayley table of the group $\mathbb{Z}^*_{10}$ and give an explicit definition for the different homomorphisms $\psi_1 ,$$\psi_2$$\quad$ $\mathbb{Z}^*_{10}$$\to$$\mathbb{Z}^*_{10}$.

Comment: Where do we start? Do you know what the notation ${\bf Z}_{10}^*$ means? Do you know what a Cayley table of a group is? Do you know what a homomorphism is? Help us help you.

Comment: Thank you, yes i understand what homomorphism is and for the notation $\mathbb{Z} ^*_{10}$ it is the multiplicative modulo 10 but i have a problem in computing this notation and what a Cayley table of a group is.

Comment: Well, I think "Cayley table" just means the multiplication table of the group. Now, in a multiplicative group, every element has to have a multiplicative inverse. Do you know what the identity element is in ${\bf Z}_{10}^*$? Can you figure out which elements have a multiplicative inverse? Then you can write down the multiplication table for those elements (under multiplication modulo $10$). By the way, if you want to be sure I'll see a comment addressed to me, you have to write @Gerry.

Comment: @BulouDuikoro: In fact, the Cayley table tells you everything you could possibly want about a group, because it tells you exactly what the operation on the group is. You can use it to compute any product, you can use it to figure out inverses, and....

Comment: You have to do better than that. You don't understand "multiplication table of the group"? You don't understand "multiplicative inverse"? You don't understand "identity element"? You don't understand "modulo $10$"?

Comment: @GerryMyerson  the identity element: $\mathbb{a}$ $\cdot$ 1 $\equiv$ $\mathbb{a}$$\quad$ ($\mathbb{mod}$$\quad$ ${n}$)and as for the multiplicative inverse and modulo 10, yes i don't understand

Comment: OK. Multiplication modulo $10$ mena s you multiply the two numbers, divide by $10$, and just keep the remainder. So, in this group, $4\times3=2$, because $2$ is the remainder when you divide $12$ by $10$. The multiplicative inverse of $a$ is the number $b$, if it exists, such that $ab\equiv1\pmod{10}$.

Answer (score 1):

Here are simple steps you may follow.
1.List the non zero element of modular 10 which are 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 .
2.Determine the value of gdc(k,n)=1
i.e gcd(1,10)=1 , gcd(2,10)=2,gcd(**3**,10)=1, gcd(4,10)=2,gcd(5,10)=5,gcd(6,10)=2,gcd(7,10)=1,gcd(8,10)=2,gcd(9,10)=1.
3.The elements you need to form the Cayley table are 1,3,7,9